# regarding jquery slideout div

Tags: jquery

i want that when user scroll down to absolute bottom then a div should come out from right side and when user click on close button then it slide in to right. i got a sample code which is very such similar but i want that when reach bottom then div should come out. so here i am giving code and just tell me what to change.

```
<p id="last">
Some paragraph text
</p>

<div id="slidebox">
<a class="close"></a>
<p>More in Technology & Science (4 of 23 articles)</p>
<h2>The Social Impact of Scientific Research and new Technologies</h2>
<a class="more">Read More »</a>
</div>

$(function() {
$(window).scroll(function(){
    var distanceTop = $('#last').offset().top - $(window).height();

    if  ($(window).scrollTop() > distanceTop)
        $('#slidebox').animate({'right':'0px'},300);
    else
        $('#slidebox').stop(true).animate({'right':'-430px'},100);
});

$('#slidebox .close').bind('click',function(){
    $(this).parent().remove();
});
});
```

i think this line **if  ($(window).scrollTop() > distanceTop)** need to be changed to determine that user reach bottom most of the page.

full source code and demo url is
http://tympanus.net/codrops/2010/04/13/end-of-page-slide-out-box/

http://tympanus.net/Tutorials/EndPageSlideOutBox/

thanks

Comment: What happens when you remove .offset() from line 3 of your javascript?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not quite sure what part to play that `.last` has, but if you want to show the container when the user reaches the bottom of the web page, you can use something like this:

```
if($(window).scrollTop() == ($('body').height() - $(window).height()))
    $('#slidebox').animate({'right':'0px'},300);
else
    $('#slidebox').stop(true).animate({'right':'-430px'},100);
```

See a demo as the following [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GoranMottram/kAJC5/).

Comment: i got the success here is my full code http://jsfiddle.net/tridip/wjvbK/   thanks

Answer (score 0):

The line `var distanceTop = $('#last').offset().top - $(window).height();` is effectively calculating "when the `#last` element appears at the bottom of the screen", and that's when your box is animating.

I think you want `var distanceTop = $('#last').offset().top + $(window).height();` which should be "when the `#last` element appears at the top of the screen".

Comment: i dont want to work with $('#last').offset().top rather want to calculate just user has reached bottom of the page or not....if reached bottom of the page then i will do something. thanks guide me.